# How to prove (L+M)* = M*.(L.M*)*

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions, proof-techniques

Question is to simplify (LM*)* and I couldn't figure out a way to simplify it. Since (L+M)* = M*.(L.M*)*, I guess we can say that it cannot be simplified more. So how do we prove that they are the same and expression $(LM^*)^*$ cannot be simplified more

Comment: what are L and M

Comment: @SubhankarGhosal regular expressions